# Which theorem of homotopy theory states that if two objects have different genus then they are not homotopy equivalent?

Tags: homotopy-theory

I'm quite new inexperienced in the field but from what I see two objects with different genus are not homotopy equivalent.

Question: Which theorem of homotopy theory states that if two objects have different genus then they are not homotopy equivalent?

Comment: In fact the more natural theorem is that if two objects are homotopy equivalent, then they have the same genus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for closed surfaces of genus $g$, the Euler characteristic is uniquely determined:

\begin{equation}
\chi=2-2g.
\end{equation}

Now, the Euler characteristic can be defined as the alternating sum of the Betti numbers (i.e. the ranks of the singular homology groups):

$$\chi = b_0 - b_1 + b_2 + \cdots $$

These homology groups are isomorphic for any two homotopy-equivalent spaces, and thus the Betti numbers coincide.  Hence the Euler characteristic is a homotopy invariant, and we also obtain that the genus $g$ must be the same for all homotopy-equivalent spaces.